# Can I divide a /28 network into two /29 networks?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, cidr

I have a
`192.168.1.64 /28`  Network

Can I divde this network into

```
192.168.1.64/29
```

and

```
192.168.1.72/29
```

?

My Question is related to the fact that now the "network address" (192.168.1.64) of the /28 is shared also by the 192.168.1.64/29 network.

And the Broadcast address (192.168.1.79) of the /28 network is now shared by the  192.168.1.72/29 network.

Is this allowed? Or do I have to, if I split the /28, make sure that the network/broadcast addresses do not overlap? Do I have to use a /30 if I subdivide the /28 network?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, easily - the 'network address' is something of a misnomer in this situation as you'll kind of have two, what you really need to care about is the fact that you'll now need two default gateways, one per /29.

Essentially what you'll have is;

- 192.168.1.64 - 'network address' of first /29 subnet - could theoretically be used as default gateway.
- 192.168.1.65 - likely real DG for first /29 subnet
- 192.168.1.66 - server IP #1
- 192.168.1.67 - server IP #2
- 192.168.1.68 - server IP #3
- 192.168.1.69 - server IP #4
- 192.168.1.70 - server IP #5
- 192.168.1.71 - broadcast address for first /29 subnet
- 192.168.1.72 - 'network address' of second /29 subnet - could theoretically be used as default gateway.
- 192.168.1.73 - likely real DG for second /29 subnet
- 192.168.1.74 - server IP #1
- 192.168.1.75 - server IP #2
- 192.168.1.76 - server IP #3
- 192.168.1.77 - server IP #4
- 192.168.1.78 - server IP #5
- 192.168.1.79 - broadcast address for second /29 subnet

Hope this helps, oh and I'm sure you know but a /29 works out as 255.255.255.248.

Comment: I like to think of it this way: when subnetting an existing network, you "throw away" the network you started with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
# ipcalc -mnb 192.168.1.64/28
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
BROADCAST=192.168.1.79
NETWORK=192.168.1.64

# ipcalc -mnb 192.168.1.64/29
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
BROADCAST=192.168.1.71
NETWORK=192.168.1.64

# ipcalc -mnb 192.168.1.72/29
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
BROADCAST=192.168.1.79
NETWORK=192.168.1.72
```

The overlapping you mention should be of no concern, since for most purposes you won't be using 192.168.1.64/28 (except for aggregation in routing, which would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let's consider `/29` which is equal to `255.255.255.248` that is `11111111.11111111.11111111.11111000` in binary representation where `11111111.11111111.11111111.11111` is the network section and `000` is the hosts section.

Therefore the following is possible.

(I've separated the hosts section with a space in the binary representation)

```
Sub net mask
=============
<-------- network section------><-hosts->
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111   000
```

```
Network A available IPs: 192.168.0.0/29
========================================
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   000 (reserved) - 192.168.0.0
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   001            - 192.168.0.1
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   010            - 192.168.0.2
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   011            - 192.168.0.3
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   100            - 192.168.0.4
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   101            - 192.168.0.5
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   110            - 192.168.0.6
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000   111 (reserved) - 192.168.0.7
```

```
Network B available IPs: 192.168.0.8/29
========================================
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   000 (reserved) - 192.168.0.8
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   001            - 192.168.0.9
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   010            - 192.168.0.10
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   011            - 192.168.0.11
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   100            - 192.168.0.12
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   101            - 192.168.0.13
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   110            - 192.168.0.14
11000000.10101000.00000000.00001   111 (reserved) - 192.168.0.15
```